# Monte Carlo Marcov Chain with pymc

Tags: python, pymc, markov-chains, mcmc

I'm trying to build a MCMC model to simulate a changing beavior over time. I have to simulate one day with a time interval of 10-minutes. I have several observations of one day from N users in 144 intervals. So I have  `U_k=U_1,...,U_N`  U users with k ranging from 1 to N and for each user I have `X_i=X_1,...X_t` samples. Each user has two possible states, 1 and 0. I have understood that I have to build a transition probability matrix for each time step and then run the MCMC model. Is it right? But I did not understood how to build it in pyMC can anybody provided me suggestion?

Comment: does this help: https://martin-thoma.com/python-markov-chain-packages/ ?

Comment: What does your data look like? What have you tried? What is the behaviour that you are simulating? What are your examples? What is t? Needs more information!

Comment: Hi @KenSyme t is the time from 1,..,144. The data are in matrix Nx144 where N are different observations (one for each user).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, assuming each user behaves the same way in a particular time interval, at each interval t we can get the matrix
[ Pr 0->0 , Pr 1->0;
  Pr 1->0 , Pr 1->0]

where Pr x ->y = (the number of people in interval t+1 who are in state y AND who were in state x in interval t) divided by (the number of people who were in state x in interval t), i.e. the probability based on the sample that someone in the given time interval in state x (0 or 1) will transition to state y (0 or 1) in the next time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Just googling `pymc` and `mcmc` lead me to ["Just the theory, the next pages are about the implementation"](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/theory.html)

I'd propose you to browse through this document and try the examples in there, this will put you on the right track.

Comment: I have read the documentaion but I did not find answer to my question.